# Bitonic Sort in Multithread (threads conflict)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sorting

I have a problem with the correct sorting using multithreading. Bitonic sorting works correctly in a SingleThread, but in MultiThread returns not quite the correct result. What can be a problem? I suspect that this may be some conflict of threads (race condition)?

```
public class MultiThreadedSorter : BaseBitonicSorter
{
    private int minimumLength = 1;

    public override void Sort(ref int[] array)
    {
        a = array;
        minimumLength = a.Length / Environment.ProcessorCount; // przydział procesów
        BitonicSort(new BitonicParameters(0, a.Length, Ascending));
    }

    private void BitonicSort(object AsyncState)
    {
        BitonicParameters parameters = (BitonicParameters)AsyncState;
        if (parameters.Length > 1)
        {
            if (parameters.Length > minimumLength)
            {
                int median = parameters.Length / 2;
                Thread left = new Thread(BitonicSort);
                Thread right = new Thread(BitonicSort);
                left.Start(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, median, Ascending));
                right.Start(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index + median, median, Descending));
                left.Join();
                right.Join();
            }
            else
            {
                int median = (parameters.Length / 2);
                if (median > 1)
                {
                    BitonicSort(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, median, Ascending));
                    BitonicSort(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, median, Ascending));
                }
            }
            BitonicMerge(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, parameters.Length, parameters.Direction));
        }
    }

    private void BitonicMerge(object AsyncState)
    {
        BitonicParameters parameters = (BitonicParameters)AsyncState;
        if (parameters.Length > 1)
        {
            if (parameters.Length > minimumLength)
            {
                int median = (parameters.Length / 2);

                for (int i = parameters.Index; i < (parameters.Index + median); i++)
                {
                    Compare(i, (i + median), parameters.Direction);
                }
                Thread left = new Thread(BitonicMerge);
                Thread right = new Thread(BitonicMerge);
                left.Start(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, median, parameters.Direction));
                right.Start(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index + median, median, parameters.Direction));
                left.Join();
                right.Join();
            }
            else
            {
                int median = (parameters.Length / 2);

                for (int i = parameters.Index; i < (parameters.Index + median); i++)
                {
                    Compare(i, (i + median), parameters.Direction);
                }
                if (median > 1)
                {
                    BitonicMerge(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index, median, parameters.Direction));
                    BitonicMerge(new BitonicParameters(parameters.Index + median, median, parameters.Direction));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private struct BitonicParameters
    {
        public BitonicParameters(int index, int length, bool direction)
        {
            Index = index;
            Length = length;
            Direction = direction;
        }
        public int Index;
        public int Length;
        public bool Direction;
    }
}

public class SingleThreadedBitonicSorter : BaseBitonicSorter
{

    public override void Sort(ref int[] array)
    {
        a = array;
        BitonicSort(0, a.Length, Ascending);
    }

    private void BitonicSort(int index, int length, bool direction)
    {
        if (length > 1)
        {
            int median = (length / 2);
            if (median > 1)
            {
                BitonicSort(index, median, Ascending);
                BitonicSort(index + median, median, Descending);
            }
            BitonicMerge(index, length, direction);
        }
    }

    private void BitonicMerge(int index, int length, bool direction)
    {
        if (length > 1)
        {
            int median = (length / 2);

            for (int i = index; i < (index + median); i++)
            {
                Compare(i, (i + median), direction);
            }
            if (median > 1)
            {
                BitonicMerge(index, median, direction);
                BitonicMerge((index + median), median, direction);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A *lot* of things. This code modifies common state without locking, you have a recursive algorithm that starts threads that can't work unless their *child* threads complete but don't. A multithreaded algorithm should *not* modify state at all if possible. Each task should return data to its parent task. Which, by the way, suggests one possible way of implementing this algorithm - start from the single-threaded algorithm and convert each recursive call to a task with Task.Run. That won't be very efficient though as each Task has its own overhead, and so does thread switching

Comment: A better idea would be to partition the data in advance, depending on the number of processors, then process each partition in parallel using the single-threaded version. You don't gain anything if you create 1024 nested threads on a machine with only 4 cores. Only 4 of them are going to run at any time.

Comment: Just checked the algorithm. Using threads and recursion in a brute-force way *isn't* going to produce a good result. The algorithm is meant to work as a network of independent comparisons that could be performed in parallel. A comparison is typically a single CPU operation. Starting a *thread* to do it is serious overkill. The comparisons though aren't arbitrary, and the stages are fixed. The *indexes* of the elements that need comparing are fixed for each stage.

Comment: This means that you can partition the data and compare pairs in each step as long as you know which set of indexes to use. In stage 1 you compare items 1-2, 3-4 etc. In stage two you compare 1-3, 2-4 etc. You could split the data in four parts and have each core process the same data with different indexes in each stage.

Comment: Anyone who votes to close this question should **seriously** consider that *they* lack the the necessary knowledge to understand the question, much less vote to close it. Simply *google* for `bitonic sort`. I was surprised by the algorithm's elegance. And NO you can't parallelize the single-threaded code - bitonic is a *parallel* algorithm and the recursive version is essentially pseudocode

Comment: [bitonic sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) is a *parallel* algorithm. The recursive version is essentially pseuodocode. The algorightm uses a *network* of nodes, each one performing a simple comparison operation. This is extremely easy to parallelize in hardware and/or using SIMD operations, like [Vector.GreaterThan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector.greaterthan(v=vs.111).aspx). It's not that easy with CPU cores where accessing the cache is a lot faster than accessing an array in RAM and cross-core communication is expensive

Comment: A somewhoat inefficient implementaion is used as an example in [How to: Use parallel_invoke to Write a Parallel Sort Routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728066.aspx). The merge operations are performed using `parallel_invoke` in C++, `Parallel.Invoke` in C#. This *avoids* creating expensive threads at each iteration - both functions use threads/tasks from a pool of threads. It's not as efficient, since it doesn't actually build a network. On the other hand the code is almost the *same* as the single threaded code, using `Parallel.Invoke` to run partitioned steps in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis. Your comments have been very helpful in finding the solution.